# How do I create this pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
Point_1 = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 10  : '))
if Point_1 not in range(1, 11):
    print('this number is invalid')
else:
    for i in range(Point_1):
        print('*  '*Point_1, end=''+'\n')
```

Current Output:

```
*  *  *  
*  *  *  
*  *  *
```

Desired Output:

```
*  *  *  
 *  *  *  
*  *  *
```

Comment: If `i` is odd, print an extra space at the beginning.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon exactly. That's the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as @JohnGordon said in the comments, every odd number add a space at the beginning of the line

```
Point_1 = int(input('Enter a number between 1 et 10  : '))
if Point_1 not in range(1, 11):
    print('this number is invalid')
else:
    for i in range(Point_1):
        if (i % 2) != 0:
            print(' * '*Point_1, end=''+'\n')
        else:
            print('*  '*Point_1, end=''+'\n')
```